# flow control in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert a  SQL Server query to MYSQL, but am having trouble with the IF statements. In the SQL Server version, they are used to direct the flow of the query based on a flag, but I cannot get it to work in MYSQL. I have outlined how the code works below:

The script sets a flag based upon how much data can be matched between the query and the database.

It then performs a select statement based upon the flag: if flag=1 select a,b,c where *match logic*

else if flag=2 select  d,e,f where *different match logic*

I have tried using both IF and CASE WHEN, neither of which work. I would normally have put the IF within the WHERE clause, but different columns are selected depending upon the flag.

Is there a function that will perform IF/ELSE flows MYSQL?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: MySQL needs a shell around that - a procedure, function, trigger, ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the types and number of columns are compatible, you could do:

```
select a, b, c
from t
where (v_flag = 1) and match_condition_1
union all
select d, e, f
from t
where (v_flag = 2) and match_condition_2;
```

The alternative is to use a stored procedure.  In MySQL, the `if` control flow statement is only allowed in programming blocks -- stored procedures, stored functions, and trigger.

Comment: Thanks! Union didn't work as there are different numbers of columns being selected in each select statement, so I've put it in a stored procedure.